# Invariant subspace always exists for square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, invariance, invariant-subspace

A bonus question given to us in Linear Algebra 2 course.

> Let $A$ be any squared $n\times n$ matrix with real elements, then
>   exists subspace $W \subset R$ of dimension 1 or 2 where $W$ is invariant
>   under $A$.

First of all, I have no idea how to begin proving this, a hint is given.

> Given a squared $n \times n $ matrix $A$ with real elements and
>   vectors $a,b,c,d \subset R^n$ where $a+bi$ is eigenvector with
>   eigenvalue $c+di$, show that $Span_R\{a,b\} \subset R^n$ is invariant
>   under $A$ over field $R$.

I am stuck with both questions, I can't seem to prove either; I know it's somehow relevant to Jordan form and characteristic polynomial.

How would someone go on starting such question?

Comment: What is the ''degree'' of a subspace? Do you means the dimension?

Comment: Yes, by degree I mean dimension; edited.

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Comment: Yes, I have studied it. Where would it come to play? in the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Yep. That's pretty much the only polynomial you've got. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes
So, $A(a+bi) = (a+bi)(c+di)=(ca-db)+i(da+cb)=Aa+iAb$.

Since $A$ is real then $Aa=ca-db$ and $Ab=da+cb$ then $A(\alpha a+\beta b)=\alpha Aa+\beta Ab \in span(a,b)$

That will prove the hint.. and then I am stuck again...

Unless saying $0 < dim(span(a,b)) \le 2$ is acceptable, but I must show an eigenvector exists for it, no? I can say so because $C$ is closed algebraically so exists a root of the polynomial that is complex number..

I think I solved it; is the proof idea correct? I just need to write it formally; however it'snot wrong is it?

Comment: That list of equalities at the start doesn't even make sense. From the fact that you wrote it, I infer that you really need help on the more basic topics like "matrix vector multiplication", "eigenvectors and eigenvalues", and, perhaps most critically, what constitutes a proof and how one would write a proof. Someone else will have to take over from here. In the meantime, I suggest a review of those topics.

Comment: The proposition is false when $A$ is the zero matrix.

Comment: The equality makes sense when you consider that $a+bi$ is a eigenvector with eigenvalue $c+id$

Comment: @amd
Shouldn't every subspace contain the zero vector? since you can multiple any base vector with the constant 0?

Comment: The only invariant space of the zero matrix is the trivial subspace consisting of just the zero vector, but the dimension of this space is neither 1 nor 2.